# Why does multiplication in \dim_set:Nn crash LaTeX?

Tags: latex3

Why does multiplication in `\dim_set:Nn` cause the LaTeX to crash?

I have found that it is possible to do multiplication in `\fp_set:Nn` for example

```
\fp_set:Nn \onefloat {5 * 6}
```

works well.

But multiplication in `\dim_set:Nn` causes LaTeX to crash LaTeX:

```
\dim_set:Nn \onetest {2 * \textwidth}
```

I have also found that if the multiplication symbol in `\dim_set:Nn` is removed the document builds as expected.

```
\dim_set:Nn \onetest {2\textwidth}
```

For example, the following code will crash for me

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \onetest
\dim_set:Nn \onetest {2 * \textwidth}

\newcommand{\myfirst}{ \dim_eval:n { \onetest } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Document
\begin{document}
    Some Text.
    \myfirst
    More text
\end{document}
```

But when the * it removed

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \onetest
\dim_set:Nn \onetest {2\textwidth}

\newcommand{\myfirst}{ \dim_eval:n { \onetest } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Document
\begin{document}
    Some Text.
    \myfirst
    More text
\end{document}
```

Will run as expected.

I'm using LuaLaTex to build the document. Why does the multiplication symbol cause crashes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\dim_set:Nn`, etc., are thin wrappers around the e-TeX `\dimexpr` primitive. It has a rather restrictive syntax in terms of what is allowed: `\textwidth * 2` is OK, `2 * \textwidth` is not, as the dimension part has to come first.

In contrast, `\fp_set:Nn`, etc., are implemented in macros with parsing in the control of `expl3`. The supported syntax is therefore richer: part of this is of course that there is no *requirement* to produce an output as a dimension.

However, parsing in macros comes at the cost of performance. As such, whilst the `\dimexpr` formulation is a little tricky to use, the fact that it is *much* faster than `fp` parsing makes the balance worthwhile.